# How can I change where the customize puts custom-set-variables

Tags: customize

Basically I would like to have (custom-set-variables ...) in a seperate file and for me to load that file.

This is just for the purpose of organisation of my init file.

How can I change the default location of custom-set-variables?

Comment: Good question. Not enough users make use of `custom-file`, IMO. The Emacs doc should make it more prominent, and even provide for it being used by default, rather than letting Customize pollute the init file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set the `custom-file` variable in your init file.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `custom-file` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: And note that although this is a user option, you probably do not want to count on setting it only using Customize, i.e., setting it in your `custom-file'. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Example of exact text you may want to place in your `init.el`:

```el
(setq custom-file (concat user-emacs-directory "custom.el"))
(load custom-file 'noerror)
```

Comment: I think this is the better answer here.

Comment: Thank you. I do not know why sometimes emacs guides leave out examples and exact text. I think it makes it harder for beginners.